# How can I find and ignore different data within a CSV file?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file that has names, ID, and hashtags for different TV shows:

```
NAME: The Venture Bros. -    ID: 187 -      HASHTAG: VentureBros
NAME: Friday Night Lights -  ID: 141 -      HASHTAG: FNL
NAME: Curb Your Enthusiasm - ID: 30 -       HASHTAG: CurbYourEnthusiasm
NAME: Sleepy Hallow -        ID:  -       HASHTAG: SleepyHallow
NAME: The Blacklist -        ID:  -       HASHTAG: TheBlacklist
NAME: The Following -        ID: 3958 -   HASHTAG: TheFollowing
```

I wrote a script in Ruby to output to the terminal. Here is my code:

```
require 'csv'

csv_text = File.read('hashtags.csv')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)

csv.each do |row|
  hastag = row['HASHTAG'].sub! '#', ''
  puts "NAME: #{row['NAME']} - \tID: #{row['ID']} - \tHASHTAG: #{row['HASHTAG']}"
end
```

I need to write something that will go through the CSV file and ignore the shows that DO NOT have an ID assigned to them.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Be very careful using `File.read('hashtags.csv')`. This is a scalability problem; Files grow over time and you can run into problems loading the data into memory. Instead of reading, parsing, then iterating over the resulting `csv` array, use `CSV.foreach` to open and iterate over the file row by row. There is no scalability problem then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a conditional `if row['ID'].nil?` to the end of the print statement:

```
    puts "NAME: #{row['NAME']} - \tID: #{row['ID']} - \tHASHTAG: #{row['HASHTAG']}" if row['ID'].nil?
```

Comment: Here is what I'm getting for your code @Oliver
`hashtags1.rb:9:in `block in <main>': undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
 from /Users/Taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:846:in `each'
 from /Users/Taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:846:in `each'
 from hashtags1.rb:6:in `<main>'`

Comment: Replace `if row['ID'].empty?` with `unless row['ID'].nil?`